# HttpListener in Azure cloud service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

I am trying to develop a service to be deployed as an Azure Cloud Service. This service needs to listen for HttpRequests, and process them as they're received.

Thus far, I have created a simple Azure Cloud Service project in VS2017 with a single worker-role, which handles requests sent to /Localhost:8080/ like so:

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        this.runasync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token).Wait();
    }
    finally
    {
        this.runCompleteEvent.Set();
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
        bool result = base.OnStart();
        Trace.TraceInformation("WorkerRole1 has been started");
        return result;
    }

    private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Listen("http://Localhost:8080/", 50, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task Listen(string prefix, int maxConcurrentRequests, CancellationToken token)
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
        listener.Start();

        var requests = new HashSet<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxConcurrentRequests; i++)
            requests.Add(listener.GetContextAsync());

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Task t = await Task.WhenAny(requests);
            requests.Remove(t);

            if (t is Task<HttpListenerContext>)
            {
                var context = (t as Task<HttpListenerContext>).Result;
                requests.Add(ProcessRequestAsync(context));
                requests.Add(listener.GetContextAsync());
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        //Specific handling logic here...
    }
}
```

I will replace Localhost:8080 with the URL of the cloudservice once created.

I am using POSTMAN to send requests to the service for testing, but on the live environment, the requests will be sent from a server hosting a web-page; which will interact with users.
However, thus far, I have only been able to receive requests sent from/to the local machine I'm developing on.

How do I expose this HttpListener to remote requests, as a service running on Azure?

I am very new to working with Azure, and my search for helpful articles hasn't yielded a solid guide on how to set this up properly, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: `await Listen("http://+:8080/", 50, cancellationToken);`

Comment: @L.B This definetely helped!  
The service is now running on Azure, and responds if I address the worker directly (I still think that there is a better approach to Azure services and HttpListening, but cheers!)